# Don't start ASP.NET Development Server when running non-web projects

Tags: asp.net, debugging, visual-studio-2010

I have a solution with a few projects in it, one of which is a web site. When I run one of the non-web projects (e.g. a console app), the ASP.NET Development Server starts up anyway.

I'm sure there was an option for this somewhere - how do I make the ASP.NET Development Server start only if I am running the web project?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, if you select the project, there is a start when debugging option (or similarly named) in the project properties window in VS; setting this to false disables this.

HTH.

Comment: Ah, thanks. "Always Start When Debugging." I always look for these things in the properties pages (when you right-click the project and choose Properties) but forget about the properties view (when you press F4).

Comment: To find this option, you must select the project in Solution Explorer then look in the Properties tool window.  It is not found when opening the Properties node within the project.

Comment: Yes it is, at least for VS 2010 Ultimate/Professional.  It was right there for me.